# Git log - How to filter (exclude) files from appearing in `git log`? (git pathspec magic)

Tags: git, git-commit, git-log

I need to use the `git-log` command to create a report of the number of added and removed lines by commit, on average between two dates.

Currently the command I use is:

```
git log --since="2015-12-01" --until="2015-12-31" --shortstat
```

But I need to filter some files in the process.
Thoses files are autogenerated, and we don't want to see their influence. They are easily recognizes by their name `*.generated.*`

I choose to use the `git-log` command, I am able to get the report I need, except I don't see how to filter those unwanted files.

[The doc is big](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log), I already read it several times, but I don't see anything about filtering files based on their names. Is this possible, or do I have to find another command to find the number of lines added/deleted by commit?

Comment: Why do you even keep generated files under version control?! I'd say that's the actual issue.

Comment: Let's say that's another issue for another team where I have no power :)

Comment: Would running the result through `grep -vF '.generated.'` do?

Comment: the git log command does not enumerate all files. You just get how many files have been modified (add or deleted) in one commit

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The "secret" on how to do it is called:

---

### ***`pathspec magic`***

---

You Can simply use this format (introduced in git version >1.9):

```
# Use this syntax, pay attention to all the parameters and the syntax

# Unix: 
git log <any required flags> -p  -- . ':(exclude)*.generated.*'

# Windows (double quote) [ Thank to @Cyril Gandon for noticing it]:
# (double quote) should work on all OS as well
git log <any required flags> -p  -- . ":(exclude)*.generated.*"
```

---

#### What is this weird syntax?

This syntax is called ***`pathspec magic`***.
Using this syntax you can "tell" git which file extensions to exclude. In your case it's the ***`*.generated.*`***

---

#### From the doc:

***`http://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary.html`***:

> A ***pathspec*** that begins with a colon `:` has special meaning.
>
> In the short form, the leading colon `:` is followed by zero or more `magic signature` letters (which optionally is terminated by another colon :), and the remainder is the pattern to match against the path.
>
> The `magic signature` consists of ASCII symbols that are neither alphanumeric, glob, regex special characters nor colon. The optional colon that terminates the `magic signature` can be omitted if the pattern begins with a character that does not belong to "magic signature" symbol set and is not a colon.
>
> In the long form, the leading colon `:` is followed by a open parenthesis (, a comma-separated list of zero or more ***`magic words`***, and a close parentheses ), and the remainder is the pattern to match against the path.

---

***Note***

In older versions (the feature was introduced in git v1.9 and the bug was fixed in git 1.9.5) there was a bug which was fixed.

https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed22b4173bd8d6dbce6236480bd30a63dd54834e

---

#### ***Demo:***

#### ***`git log --stat`***

(check the last commit)
[image]

And the same runt with the filer - you can see that there is only one file in the results instead of 2

#### **`git log --stat -p -- . ':(exclude)*dal.js*'`**

[image]

Comment: This is documented in the [gitglossary](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html) man page (and apparently almost nowhere else).

Comment: Agreed, this why i added it + doc :-). Its not a simply question and you need to know git pretty well to answer it. :-)

Comment: This looks like sorcery. what does `-p  -- . ` means? I tried `git log --since="2015-12-01" --until="2015-12-31" --shortstat  -p  -- . ':(exclude)*.generated.*'` but I got a whole lot of new lines, specifically each files are returned in the stdout, with the diff for each files. Is that normal?

Comment: `-p` stands for <path>, `.` stands for the current directory (recursive) and yep the result is normal :-)

Comment: What ever I put in the exclusion pattern, the result neverchange, files are still take into account even if I try to exclude them. Even *.* return something, I was expected that `git log --since="2015-12-01" --until="2015-12-31" --shortstat -p -- . ':(exclude)*.*'` to be empty

Comment: I added a sample screenshot to show you how it should look like.

Comment: If yo uwant to elude them all use this: `':(exclude)*'` (ant not `*.*`)

Comment: I have to be particulary incompetent today :) `git log --stat -p -- . ':(exclude)*'` still give me result. It's like exclusion doesn't do a thing. Could it be a git version problem?

Comment: Which git version are you using, its only working from certain version and above:-)

Comment: I have breathe, and it's working like a charm now. Don't know why it didn't work, but thank you!

Comment: I KNOW, it was quote! on windows you need double quote :)

Comment: @codeWizard : typo in your comment `git log -p` : `-p` stands for *patch*, and is not necessary in your examples, nor for the OP's needs. It displays a detailed diff for each listed commit.

Comment: Thanks! Also, good to know you can add more than one e.g. `git log -p v3.5.0~..master -- . ':(exclude)yarn.lock' ':(exclude)README.md'`

Comment: Apparently this also works in newer git versions: `git log -- :!<path>`, could not find documentation for it